# aligning two elements horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am trying to find a way to align perfectly the left and right section under the two HR elements. I want the HR elements to be on the same line, for now it seems the right section is a bit higher then the left one. I tried to use align self but it doesn't work the way I want. Is there any other solution I could implement?[image]

My code for now:

```
  <footer>
      <div class="info">
        <hr />
        <info class="info__wrap">
          <div class="info-el">Company</div>
          <div class="info-el">Contact us</div>
          <div class="info-el">Career</div>
          <div class="info-el">Privacy policy</div>
          <div class="info-el">Terms</div>
        </info>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-logo">
        <img src="img/logo-green-1x.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="copyright">
        <hr/>
        Build by Jonas Schmedtmann for his online course advanced CSS and SASS. Copyright by Joanas Schmedtman. You are 100% allowed to use this webpage for both personal and commercial uses, but not to claim it is your design.
      </div>
    </footer>


    footer {
  background-color: $color-grey-dark-3;
  display: flex;
  height: 40rem;
  align-items: center;
  color: $color-white;
  justify-content: space-around;

    }

.info__wrap {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 70%;

}

.footer-logo {
  align-self: flex-start;
  padding-top: 5rem;
}

.copyright {
  width: 30rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.info-el {
  padding-right: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Note: the `<hr>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option is to change the `align-items: center;` directive to `align-items: flex-start;` and apply a `padding-top` to the items of a fixed amount. I found pixels or rem to work, personally.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what u r expecting:

```css
footer {
  background-color: $color-grey-dark-3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 40rem;
  align-items: center;
  color: $color-white;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
}

.info__wrap {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 70%;
}

.footer-logo {
  padding-top: 5rem;
}

.copyright {
  width: 30rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.info-el {
  padding-right: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer-logo">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="info">
      <hr />
      <info class="info__wrap">
        <div class="info-el">Company</div>
        <div class="info-el">Contact us</div>
        <div class="info-el">Career</div>
        <div class="info-el">Privacy policy</div>
        <div class="info-el">Terms</div>
      </info>
    </div>
    <div class="copyright">
      <hr/> Build by Jonas Schmedtmann for his online course advanced CSS and SASS. Copyright by Joanas Schmedtman. You are 100% allowed to use this webpage for both personal and commercial uses, but not to claim it is your design.
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```